# Auto Generate Code base on Date

Tags: sql-server

I would like to ask how can I generate batch code base on production_date column?

My Query:

```
SELECT  receiving_detail.con_id,   
         receiving_detail.ITEM_ID,      
         receiving_detail.TRANSACTION_QTY,   
         receiving_detail.UNIT_COST,  
         receiving_detail.UOM_ID,   
            item_master_list.item_code,  
            receiving_detail.po_item_id,
            receiving_detail.production_date,
            receiving_detail.expiration_date,
            receiving_detail.batch_code
    FROM receiving_detail   left join item_master_list on item_master_list.id=receiving_detail.item_id
```

Expected Output:

```
con_id  ITEM_ID item_code   production_date expiration_date batch_code
413797  366     508246      2018-01-17       2018-07-17     180117
415012  108101  512761      2018-01-17       2019-01-17     180117
339027  27      301283      2017-09-19       2018-01-17     180117
```

Comment: what code, are you looking for a new column with code, unique for each date?

Comment: I would like to fill batch_code column base on production_date column.

Comment: _based in what way? please explain Do you want the existing _receiving_detail.batch_code_ in your dataset or do you want to replace it?

Comment: that's the expected output for the receiving_detail.batch_code column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  receiving_detail.con_id,   
         receiving_detail.ITEM_ID,      
         receiving_detail.TRANSACTION_QTY,   
         receiving_detail.UNIT_COST,  
         receiving_detail.UOM_ID,   
            item_master_list.item_code,  
            receiving_detail.po_item_id,
            receiving_detail.production_date,
            receiving_detail.expiration_date,
            convert(varchar, receiving_detail.production_date, 12) AS batch_code

    FROM receiving_detail   left join item_master_list on item_ma
```

Comment: It is possible to also input the day only of expiration_date column in batch_code?

Comment: Sorry i didnt get. Right now batch_code takeing production_date. can you explain what you expecting?

Comment: the batch_code for con_id 413797 will be 18011707 the last two digits is came from the day of expiration_date column.

Comment: like this. `convert(varchar, receiving_detail.production_date, 12) + convert(varchar(2), receiving_detail.expiration_date, 110)`